# Why do I get extra space above the image?

Tags: html, css

I want to move down the red div like my example but I still get extra space above the image div (class two), like the red div is still there in the top of the page.

How can I solve this in a better way? I don't want to use absolute position because my site is responsive and set the Image div (class two) to `top: -50px` sounds like bad solution.

```css
    .one {
      top: 100px;
      position: relative;
      width: 100px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="one">Some text</div>
    <div class="two">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
    </div>
```

Comment: Remove the `top:100px` property

Comment: they specifically mention not wanting to use absolute positioning. This will be hard without moving dom elements around and using background image instead.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w33wudry/4/

Comment: I still want to move down the red div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
    .one {
      top: 100px;
      position: relative;
      width: 100px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: red;
      margin-bottom: -50px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="one">Some text</div>
    <div class="two">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
    </div>
```

Comment: I think this is what he is asking for